# GoCardless webhook not offered

Tags: gocardless, webhook

I'm following these instructions:
In CiviCRM, visit Administer » CiviContribute » **GoCardless Webhooks**. This page will show you the URLs that you need.
The **GoCardless Webhooks** isn't available at this location, so I can't get the URL I need ?

Comment: new documentation just published at https://docs.civicrm.org/gocardless/en/latest/

Comment: and 1.9.3 just out based on https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/9x7nnuxu3tb39rk9zrcth8io5a in case either of those are welcome news